# updating many record with an array using a where clause in laravel

Tags: laravel

Please i need to update an array with a where clause , the field i am to use for the the where clause is in array

```
$promote = DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.users_role', 'Student')
    ->where($request->from_class, 'pick')
    ->update(array('users_class' => $request->to_class));
```

where `$request->from_class` is a check box from a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereIn()` method to achieve what you want

```
$promote = DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.users_role', 'Student')
    ->whereIn('pick', $request->from_class)
    ->update(array('users_class' => $request->to_class));
```